# Overlay icons in Windows

Tags: windows, icons

How to overlay an icon over a folder or a file icon. For eg. the way Tortoise SVN, Dropbox etc. put a tick mark over a file icon and a folder icon? How to do it programmatically, for eg. from VB.Net .

Comment: Since TortoiseSVN is licensed under the GPL you can read the code and learn by example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write a [Shell Icon Overlay Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Be advised that overlay icons are a tightly limited resource, which is why the various Tortoise extensions now share overlays. According to ["The overlay icons appear, but not all of them" in the TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotall), there can only be 15 overlay icons in total, and 4 of these are already used by Windows.

If you would actually be happy using the same icons as Tortoise*, you too should use TortoiseOverlays. For details on how to do this, see [TortoiseOverlays/Documentation.txt](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/src/TortoiseOverlays/Documentation.txt) in the TortoiseSVN tree.